# Merge Statement inserting duplicate rows?

Tags: sql, sql-server, merge, bulkinsert, upsert

For the eternity that I have been spending time on this, I can't seem to find the cause as to why my `MERGE` statement inserts duplicate rows. Here are my tables.

```
TABLE INVENTORY
```

```
ProductID  |   ProductName   |   ProductCode   |   Quantity   |   Location
1          |   Stabilo       |   Code123       |   3          |   Basement
2          |   Parker Pen    |   Code456       |   4          |   Basement
```

```
TABLE INCOMINGSTOCKS
```

```
REQUESTNUMBER  |  ProductID    | ProductName  | ProductCode  | Quantity  | DeliveryLocation
Request123     |  2            | Parker Pen   | Code456      | 3         | Basement
Request123     |  3            | Eraser       | Code789      | 5         | Basement
```

One request number = multiple items, much like a fast food delivery can contain multiple orders in one transaction number.
When I run this query...

```
MERGE INVENTORY as T1
USING INCOMINGSTOCKS AS T2
ON T1.ProductCode = T2.ProductCode
AND T2.REQUESTNUMBER = 'Request123' and T2.DeliveryLocation= 'Basement'
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET T1.Quantity = T1.Quantity + T2.Quantity
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT (ProductID, ProductName, ProductCode, Quantity, Location) 
VALUES (T2.ProductID, T2.ProductName, T2.ProductCode, T2.Quantity, T2.DeliveryLocation);
```

...it returns with this data:

```
ProductID  | ProductName  |  ProductCode  |  Quantity  |  Location
Stabilo    | 1            |  Code123      |  3         |  Basement
Stabilo    | 1            |  Code123      |  3         |  Basement
Parker Pen | 2            |  Code456      |  7         |  Basement
Parker Pen | 2            |  Code456      |  4         |  Basement
```

The "Eraser" item did not even get inserted! It only duplicated Stabilo (which was not in the `INCOMINGSTOCKS` table, added the quantity of `Parker Pens` (3+4) and reinserted it again this time with its initial quantity.

Please, can someone help me? Any insight or any comment regarding my query? Is there something wrong with it?
**THANK YOU!!!**

Comment: Possibly inculde a check in yoir WHERE clause for:         ISNULL (T1.ProductCode,'') != ''

Comment: Your posted `merge` statement isn't even valid. Can you post the one you actually ran?

Comment: @sstan I have corrected the merge statement, thank you.

Comment: I still don't think you actually ran that statement successfully. I get an `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'.` error.

Comment: Sorry, replaced `where` with `and`

Comment: god!, then it will work

Comment: Can't repro your problem: http://rextester.com/DAEB85559. You are clearly not stating everything. You already gave us the wrong statement a few times, it's hard to trust the rest of the question.

Comment: I actually asked a question of the same nature twice here at SO but only got a few replies. So I tried to change my query to a simpler one. Here is a link to one of the questions I submitted (but not using Merge). [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40509470/insert-data-if-not-exists-from-2-tables-and-update-otherwise)

Comment: above query wont return the data as you have mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I kinda didnt understand `T2.DestinationLocation, T2.Location, USING INCOMING STOCKS AS T2`

Anyways try like this:

```
MERGE INVENTORY as T1
USING INCOMINGSTOCKS AS T2
ON T1.ProductCode = T2.ProductCode
and T2.REQUESTNUMBER = 'Request123' and T2.DeliveryLocation = 'Basement'
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET T1.Quantity = T1.Quantity + T2.Quantity
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT (ProductID, ProductName, ProductCode, Quantity, Location) 
VALUES (T2.ProductID, T2.ProductName, T2.ProductCode, T2.Quantity, T2.DeliveryLocation);

select * from INVENTORY
```

Comment: Sorry. I have corrected the query. `T2.DestinationLocation and T2.Location are T2. DeliveryLocation.` Removed the space in `INCOMING STOCKS` to `INCOMINGSTOCKS AS T2`